# Usage of SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut

Tags: ios, easing, scenekit, easing-functions

For an instance of `SCNAction`, we can specify the property `timingMode`. We can specify this as `SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut`. It doesn't seem that this is enough, in order for this to work we must also specify `timingFunction` (right?). How would this timingFunction block look like? Most timing function examples out there take 4 parameters; this function has only one which is time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timing function and timing mode together determine the actual timing curve of an action's animation.

- If you just want linear, ease-in, ease-out, or ease-in-ease-out timing, set the [`timingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNAction/timingMode) property appropriately and leave `timingFunction` alone (set it to `nil`).
- You set both mode and function only if you want to customize the timing curve beyond those four options. When you do that, the mode determines the curve for the input to the [`timingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNAction/timingFunction).

This is a bit easier to explain graphically... here's the animation curves you get with the `Linear` and `EaseInEaseOut` timing modes, and no timing function:
[image: linear timing curve] 
[image: ease in ease out curve]

Now, suppose you want quadratic timing, where the progress of the animation is proportional to time squared (great for simulating gravity). You can do that by keeping the timing mode linear, and setting the timing function to a block/closure that returns `time * time`:
[image: squared linear timing curve]

With that combination, your timing function takes an input that varies linearly over time. If you set the timing mode to something else, though, the input to your timing function won't be linear. Here's the same `time * time` function when the timing mode is `EaseInEaseOut`:
[image: squared ease in ease out curve]

Comment: I was under the impression SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut didn't just work without setting the function. The docs are a bit unclear here. Also by looking at the result it didn't look like any easing was carried out, but that can just have been hard to perceive.